# How to mix C++ and C correctly

Tags: c++, c, ffi

I am having some problems with this: I need to write a C wrapper for a C++ library. Say I have 3 files:

- wrapper.h

  ```
  typedef struct Foo Foo;
  Foo* create_foo();
  ```
- wrapper.cpp

  ```
  extern "C" {
      #include "wrapper.h"
  }
  #include "foo.h"

  Foo* create_foo() {
      return new Foo;
  }
  ```
- foo.h

  ```
  class Foo {
  public:
      Foo();
  };
  ```

This compiles fine:

`clang++ -std=c++14 wrapper.cpp foo.h wrapper.h -shared -fPIC`

`clang++ -shared -o libbindings.so a.out`

but when compiling the program that uses the C wrapper (it is compiler and linked by the programming language that uses the wrapper - Crystal), I get an undefined reference to create_foo() and a linker error `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. How can I debug this (and what am I doing wrong)?

Comment: You told the linker to link against `libshared_library_providing_create_foo.so` by specifying the option  `-lshared_library_providing_create_foo`?

Comment: Show your `wrapper.h` (assuming that's what the C program includes).

Comment: @alk Yes, I added the so directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @melpomene It's exactly as I've described it, only a typedef and function declaration

Comment: @Zihemu I didn't ask for a description.

Comment: Adding a lib to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` helps to find the lib on run-time. You also need it on link-time. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not evaluated by the linker then. You want to show us how you compile/link the program.

Comment: You might like to read around here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/694576

Comment: @alk The wrapper? `clang++ 'pkg-config --libs --cflags dependent-lib' -std=c++14 wrapper.cpp foo.h wrapper.h -shared -fPIC` (I replaced the backticks) The program that uses the wrapper is compiled and linked by the programming language, the error is @ cc.

Comment: You don't seem to provide the entire error? What's the output before this “collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status” line?

Comment: Please show some code to reproduce the problem, too.

Comment: OK, wait a minute, let me give you the minimum code.

Comment: No, the compilation command which leads to the undefined reference error ...

Comment: OK, I edited the post

Comment: Do not add .h files to the compilation line.

Comment: There is no `Foo::Foo()` defined.

Comment: @n.m. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that (1) header files do not belong on the compilation line, so `clang++ -std=c++14 wrapper.cpp foo.h wrapper.h -shared -fPIC` should be just `clang++ -std=c++14 wrapper.cpp -shared -fPIC`  and (2) you declare a default constructor for class Foo but never define it.

Comment: @n.m. Isn't it implicitly defined?

Comment: Constructors are implicitly defined only when you don't declare them.

Comment: How to properly Mix C and C++ : you don't.

Comment: @DavidHaim Err....? C is, for better or worse, the established "lingua franca" for low-level code interfaces. What's your proposed alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

**wrapper.h** (C & C++ aware)

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H_
#define WRAPPER_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct CPPClass CPPClass;

CPPClass* CPPClass_new();
void CPPClass_do_something(CPPClass* cppclass);
int CPPClass_get_state(CPPClass* cppclass);
void CPPClass_delete(CPPClass* cppclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* WRAPPER_H_ */
```

**wrapper.cpp** (C++ only)

```
#include "wrapper.h"

class CPPClass
{
    int state;
public:
    CPPClass(): state(0) {}
    void do_something() { ++state; }
    int get_state() const { return state; }
};

extern "C" CPPClass* CPPClass_new()
{
    return new CPPClass;
}

extern "C" void CPPClass_do_something(CPPClass* cppclass)
{
    cppclass->do_something();
}

extern "C" int CPPClass_get_state(CPPClass* cppclass)
{
    return cppclass->get_state();
}

extern "C" void CPPClass_delete(CPPClass* cppclass)
{
    delete cppclass;
}
```

**use-wrapper.c** (C only)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "wrapper.h"

int main(void)
{
    CPPClass* cppclass = CPPClass_new();

    if(!cppclass)
    {
        printf("ERROR: failed to create CPPClass:\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("state: %d\n", CPPClass_get_state(cppclass));
    CPPClass_do_something(cppclass);
    printf("state: %d\n", CPPClass_get_state(cppclass));

    CPPClass_delete(cppclass);
}
```

**Compile CPP**

```
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC -o libwrapper.so wrapper.cpp
```

**Compile C**

```
gcc -o use-wrapper use-wrapper.c -L. -lwrapper -lstdc++
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./use-wrapper 
state: 0
state: 1
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a shared object named `a.out`, then another shared object named `libbindings.so` that ostensibly links to `a.out` but references nothing from it. Now if a set of input files doesn't have any undefined symbols, no libraries are searched or added to the output. So `libbindings.so` is essentially an empty library. Verify:

```
 % nm a.out | grep create_foo
 00000000000006bc T create_foo
 % nm libbindings.so | grep create_foo
 %
```

If you have several source files, you should build an *object* file from each source (use -c compilation flag), (then optionally combine the objects into a static library --- skip this step if you are not releasing static libraries) then build a shared object from previously built objects:

```
  clang++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp
  clang++ -c -fPIC bar.cpp
  clang++ -shared -o libfoobar.so foo.o bar.o
```

If you only have one source, or very few source files you can easily compile together, you can build the shared library in one step:

```
  clang++ -std=c++14 wrapper.cpp somethingelse.cpp -shared -fPIC -o libbindings.so
```

This is not recommended for large projects.

Comment: Thanks! But the other answer was more complete and might help more people, even though I understand that the whole problem was in how I built the library. Thanks, again :)