# Calling a function in a .cpp file from a .c file

Tags: c++, include, mixing

I've been struggling to solve a problem with a project I'm working on.
Lets assume I have a few files:

```
reflection.h 
sll_insert.c
record_sll.c
io_recorder.cpp
```

all of the above mentioned cpp and c files use:

```
#include "reflection.h"
```

and in `"reflection.h"` are the following declarations:

```
extern void io_recorder_fun_entry(char * name, TypedObject args[], int len);

extern void io_recorder_fun_exit(char * name, TypedObject args[], int len);
```

These two functions are implemented in `"io_recorder.cpp"` and they use another function from `"io_recorder.cpp"` called `io_record`.

now, in `"io_recorder.cpp"`, the two functions are as follows:

```
extern "C" void io_recorder_fun_entry(char * name, TypedObject args[], int len) {
    cout << "Entering function "<< name << endl; 
    io_record(args, len);
}

extern "C" void io_recorder_fun_exit(char * name, TypedObject args[], int len) {
    cout << "Exiting function "<< name << endl; 
    io_record(args, len);

}
```

When in `io_record, there are calls being made to several functions declared in reflection.h and implemented in`"record_sll.c"`.

I have 2 questions:

1. The connection between C and C++ is not working for me in that case (i have experimented with it previously with other files and it seemed to work before).
   When trying to compile I receive errors like:

   `io_recorder.cpp: In function ‘void io_recorder_fun_entry(char*, TypedObject*, int)’:`

   `io_recorder.cpp:61:79: error: conflicting declaration of ‘void io_recorder_fun_entry(char*, TypedObject*, int)’ with ‘C’ linkage
   tern "C" void io_recorder_fun_entry(char * name, TypedObject args[], int len) {`

   In file included from `io_recorder.cpp:4:0:
   reflection.h:32:13: note: previous declaration with ‘C++’ linkage
   extern void io_recorder_fun_entry(char * name, TypedObject args[], int len);`

Obviously I did something wrong and I can't figure out what.
What am I supposed to change in order for it to compile properly?

2. In previous errors, it appeared that `io_record` did not recognize the functions from `record_sll` when I used them.
   Does it have anything to do with the errors from question 1? If not, what should I do to make sure `io_record` knows them.

Thanks in advance for the help, I hope i can fix this soon.

Comment: You need `extern "C"` in your header declarations.

Comment: I did, and I get a different Error.

reflection.h:32:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant
 extern "C" void io_recorder_fun_entry(char * name, TypedObject args[], int len);

Comment: Here is a working example that may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903005/how-to-mix-c-and-c-correctly/31903685#31903685

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From the C++ point of view**, you have conflicting definition:

- in your header you declare both function as a normal c++ function (i.e. no specific calling conventions)
- in the body you define the fuction as using the C calling convention

This is a problem, because in all the compilation units using your header, the compiler will generate code using the c++ calling sequence, not knowing that your function bodies use another calling sequence. Hence the error message.

To solve the issue, you must declare the functions in both cases as `extern "C"`.

**From the C point of view** however, the `extern "C"` syntax is not recognized. So if you want to use the same header for both C++ and C, some extra gym with conditional compilation is required:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {  // this line will be compiled only if included in a .cpp file and not in a .c
#endif
    // your c function declaration go here without the extern "C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

You'll find additional info on **mixing C and C++** on [this FAQ page](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp).

Comment: Thank you, Galik said the same thing. Look at the comment I wrote to him, I get a different error now.

Comment: @baronzo1 yes,  this is because when the header is included in the c file, the c language doesn't recognize this c++ syntax. Si in the header you need to use conditional compilation

Comment: @baronzo1 I´ve edited the answer to show how to use the same header in both c an cpp files

Comment: Yes!! I did that yesterday and it solved my problem. The #ifdef was what i needed to add to the extern "c" prefix. thanks alot!